# States of spin of a quantum mechanical particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, dirac-matrices

Assuming a spin is prepared in the positive $x$-direction ($|r\rangle$) and a measuring apparatus is oriented on the $z$ axis, does this equation apply?

$$|r\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|d\rangle$$

What would the equation for $|l\rangle$ be? Explain how the equation was obtained.

Answer (score 0):

If your axis of measurement aligns with the z-axis, then it's convention to choose
$$|u\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}, |d\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix},$$
representing spin up and spin down  along the z-axis. Then your eigenstates along the x direction would be$^1$:
$$|r\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix},
|l\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$
So your equation is correct. Furthermore,
$$|l\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|u\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|d\rangle$$

$^1$ See, for example: [Spin-½ - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-%C2%BD)

Comment: I'd like to know why the sign is negative on the 2nd equation

Comment: Plug in $|u\rangle$ and $|d\rangle$, if the sign is positive you won't get $|l\rangle$